# Dataframe Comparison

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a working brute force nested for loop solution for comparing two dataframes and coming to a working solution.  I'd like to be more efficient. Let's say I have two dataframes per the sample below.  How can I append (as a string) all data from df2 into df1 where df1 does not equal df2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['blue', 2, 3, 4], 'Col2' : [90, 99, 3, 97], 'Col3' : [11, 12, 13, 14]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['blue', 2, 3, 6], 'Col2' : [90, 99, 99, 97], 'Col3' : [11, 12, 13, 14]})
```

I have tried:

```
np.where(df1.ne(df2),str(df1)+str(df2),0)
```

Results should be:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, '3 99', 0],
       ['4 6', 0, 0]])
```

This attempt to be more efficient was a memory error nightmare and is wrong.

Results in the first cell to show 'blue green' or 'blue \n green'.  Anyone have any ideas?  I'll be applying this solution to a several million by 40 dataframe every day and hoping to limit the production time for results.

Comment: What's the criteria for "not equal" here?

Comment: By append what do you mean? Append the differing rows to the end? Insert a new column with the different values? Do you have an example of your desired output?

Comment: Also - what's the output supposed to be from this?

Comment: I'd like to concatenate the string from df1 to a string from df2.  @Jon Clements The result would be a dataframe with each cell having the following format: "old new" or "old \n new".  This is really a cell by cell comparison and result.  I have been using numpy.ne for the comparison and it's working as I wanted.  'blue' does not equal 'green' and 1 != 2.

Comment: So when the values are numeric it should be "2 4"?

Comment: @TylerRussell so you could potentially end up with a sparse result?

Comment: @JonClements Yes.  See new example and result above.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ahh... except there you've put a placeholder...

Comment: @Grr Correct.  That's exactly what I'm going for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your input:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['blue', 2, 3, 4], 'Col2' : [90, 99, 3, 97], 'Col3' : [11, 12, 13, 14]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['blue', 2, 3, 6], 'Col2' : [90, 99, 99, 97], 'Col3' : [11, 12, 13, 14]})
```

Create a mask:

```
mask = df1.ne(df2)
```

Then... take your df's as strings, and concat the matching elements, fill in the nans, and take the `.values`, eg:

```
result = (df1.astype(str)[mask] + ' ' + df2.astype(str)[mask]).fillna(0).values
```

Gives you:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, '3 99', 0],
       ['4 6', 0, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Works.  I coverted this to the dataframe I needed by using: pd.DataFrame(result, index=df2.index, columns=df2.columns.tolist())

Comment: @TylerRussell huh? I thought you wanted the numpy arrays given your expected output - you've already got your DataFrame as required, leave off the `.values` - `result = (df1.astype(str)[mask] + ' ' + df2.astype(str)[mask]).fillna(0)`

Comment: @TylerRussell No need to re-create it when you've already got it.

Comment: Just realized if I remove the .values, I have the df.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method to apply a function that checks for equality along each column, returning the desired output for True or False values.

```
df1.apply(lambda x: np.where(x != df2[x.name], x.map(str).str.cat(df2[x.name].map(str), sep=' '), x))
         Col1  Col2  Col3
0  blue green  4 90    11
1         2 4  4 99    12
2         3 5  5 99    13
3         4 6  6 97    14
```

In this case you can also use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) in place of [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
df1.apply(lambda x: x.where(x == df2[x.name], x.map(str).str.cat(df2[x.name].map(str), sep=' ')))
```

Comment: I'll check it.  Thanks for providing a solution.  I'll be interested in testing the lambda function.

Comment: you could define it as a standalone function, but I tend to lean on lambdas when using `apply`, `applymap`, or `map`

Comment: Just realized that this works in the example, but not when the dataframes have different array sizes.  So if df1 is (4,3) and df2 is (3,3), then the comparison won't work...Very elegant if the size doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is a simple way to do this.

```
cond = df1!=df2
df3 = df1.where(cond,0).astype(str) + " "+ df2.where(cond,0).astype(str)
df3[ ~cond ] = 0
df3
```